# How to pass additional parameters for paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, parameters, paging

I know paging requires start and limit parameters that is passed to the controller... but I also use couple more parameters that needs to be passed... which is 'STATE' and 'ID'... I tried baseParams, params... nothing works... this is my store

```
this.myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        scope: this,
        storeId: 'myStore',
        fields: [
            { name: 'State', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ID', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            extraParams: { State: '', ID: '', start: 1, limit: 200 },
            url: 'myControl/getRecords',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'count',
                root: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

I know I don't have to use start and limit as parameters but taking them out doesn't help either.

and this is my c# method

```
public string getRecords(string State, string ID, int start, int limit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
this.myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    scope: this,
    storeId: 'myStore',
    fields: [
        { name: 'State', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'ID', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        scope: this,
        extraParams: { State: '', ID: '' },
        url: 'myControl/getRecords',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'count',
            root: 'data'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Cause paging is done by the pagingbar so you wan't need set it by yourself. The way you done it will override the paging params provided by the store (pagingbar)

Note that you can override your extraParam value by calling

```
myStore.getProxy().setExtraParam('State', 'AnyValue');
```

Comment: Thanks Sra... I tried doing that... but I get a blank page... but when I do this.myStore.load({ params: {
            start: 1,
            limit: 100
        }, I get just the first page and only 100 records...

Comment: @EagleFox Note that you need a component which controls the paging! This would then set the currentPage property of the store. That on the other hand uses the pagesize to determine the start property value (limit is always the pagesize). It's hard to say what went wrong with your code. I can just tell you that I never ever needed to set the paging properties by my own.

Comment: :)... yes sra... it was on my server side... apparently i was doing start - 1.... so it was showing me page 0... now it works...just needed another pair of eyes thanks again... and Happy New Year :)

Comment: @EagleFox Hehe, You too ;)

Answer (score 0):

**start** is the default start page and **limit** is the number of rows per page

```
 this.myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        scope: this,
        storeId: 'myStore',
        fields: [
            { name: 'State', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'ID', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            extraParams: { State: '', ID: '' },
            url: 'myControl/getRecords',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'count',
                root: 'data,

                start:0,    
                limit: 25
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```